# pagination in laravel freamwork

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hi I use `paginate()` method for pagination it work fine, but a tag in `blade` file have problem my link like this:

http://localhost/blog/admin/news/?page=2

and when i click on them i'm redirect :

http://localhost/admin/news?page=2

and get `404` error and when click link like this:

http://localhost/blog/admin/news?page=2

it's work fine. what the problem ?
Why when use http://localhost/blog/admin/news/?page=2
redirect me an other page?

thanks.

Comment: How so you generate the links, with `$news->render()` ?

Comment: @mimo yes i use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. You can use the setPath() method to choose the right path. You can see the usage of that method here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view